# I can't send emails from my Springboot app. If I use the configurations via vm options it works. but when I do the same via yaml file I get errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, email, smtp

I am trying to send email from my companyhost to the customer via my customer management system.
i use springboot and yaml configs. When I use the configurations via vm Options then it works correctly.
[vm option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7ea6.png)

But when I use the same configuration via yaml file I get two different errors based on the port number I use.

```yaml
  mail:
    host: mail.test.de
# i tried port 25, 587, 465
    port: 25
    username: myuser
    password: mypassword
    protocol: smtp
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          starttls:
           enable: false
```

**Error 1 with port number 25:**
Authentication failed
**Error 2 with port number 587:**
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 454 4.7.0 STARTTLS required ; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 454 4.7.0 STARTTLS required

I tried manipulating every single line of the configurations. port number, tls, username, password, host... didn't work either.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, edit your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

Comment: Set the starttls.enable to true instead of false, and if authentication fails, you're either using the wrong username and password, or the wrong authentication mechanism.